# getCellValueByColumnAndRow->getCalculatedValue() not working PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to figure out why result is not affected when using `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` with PHPExcel.

Am I doing something wrong?

This first version sets the result to integer 0 (trying with two different approaches to fetch the calculated value)

```
//Version 1 - generating incorrect result (should 77*5 = 385, but is 0)
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();                      
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 0, 1, '=A2*5' ); //A1 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 1, 1, 77 ); //A2
echo '<br /> Value A1= ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-
>getCellByColumnAndRow(0,1)->getValue();
echo '<br />Value A2= ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-
>getCellByColumnAndRow(1,1)->getValue();

echo '<br />Result=' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-
>getCellByColumnAndRow(0,1)->getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br />Result=' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1")-
>getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br /><br />';
```

This second version when using letters and characters to set values it works as expected:

```
//Version 2 - generating correct result (77*5 = 385)
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();                      
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( "A1", '=A2*5' ); //A1
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( "A2", 77 ); //A2
echo '<br />Value A1= ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1")-
>getValue();
echo '<br />Value A2= ' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A2")-
>getValue();
echo '<br />Result=' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1")-
>getCalculatedValue();
echo '<br />Result=' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-
>getCellByColumnAndRow(0,1)->getCalculatedValue();
```

**Output version 1:**

```
Value A1= =A2*5
Value A2= 77
Result=0
Result=0
```

**Output version 2:**

```
Value A1= =A2*5
Value A2= 77
Result=385
Result=385
```

Is this a bug in PHPEXcel or *am I simply doing something wrong*?

The reason why I want to use `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` is that I have an array like this that is created from a post request and I want recalculate changed values of the array: (The examples with version1 and version2 above were for testing how it worked with PHPExcel and has nothing to do with this array)

```
array 
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => string '6000' (length=4)
      2 => string '=A2*5' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => string '60009' (length=5)
      2 => string '=A2*5' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => string '7000' (length=4)
      2 => string '=A3*5' (length=5)
....
```

**UPDATE:**
This is not a duplicate [PHPExcel setCellValueByColumnAndRow not writing data to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468606/phpexcel-setcellvaluebycolumnandrow-not-writing-data-to-spreadsheet), because that question had nothing to do with result of formula calculations. The actual values are set within my question into the cells, but when fetching the calculated value with `getCellValueByColumnAndRow` it does not seem to work. I don't the see the connection between my question and the question that is flagged as possible duplicate. I've also changed the title of this question to  make it more clear what the actual issue is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel setCellValueByColumnAndRow not writing data to spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468606/phpexcel-setcellvaluebycolumnandrow-not-writing-data-to-spreadsheet)

Comment: @Deep 3015 - This is not a duplicate, because that question had nothing to do with result of formula calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough...

sometimes it's so easy... far to easy... I just mixed up rows and columns for some reason ):

Now it works with this code (as expected):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 0, 1, '=A2*5' ); //A1 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 0, 2, 77 ); //A2
```

**and NOT**

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 0, 1, '=A2*5' ); //A1 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow( 1, 1, 77 ); //A2
```