# PHPExcel set column value and column quantity

Tags: php, mysql, excel, select, phpexcel

I have one select statement which will result values as below:

```
  79927
  79927
  79927
  79927
  79928
  79928
  79928
  79928
  79928
```

Then When I export to excel I have the below screen: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAcp6.jpg)

But what I really want is this result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNITU.jpg)

I want to set the maximum column as D, which means every time the result achieve the column D the next will move to the next row.

If the result achieve the D1, the next will go to A2 and so on.

Here's my code:

```
        $rowCount=1;
        while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($itens_spec_comb)) {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue ('A'.$rowCount, $row1 ['id']);



        $rowCount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, use my example:

```
    $rowCount=1;
    $col = array("A","B","C","D");
    $i=0;

     while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($itens_spec_comb)) {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue ($col[$i].$rowCount, $row1 ['id']);
            $i++;
            if($i==3){
                 $i=0;
                 $rowCount++;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Exactly! I just did the change of  if($i==3){ to  if($i==4){      Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $rowCount=1;
    while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($itens_spec_comb)) {

        for($col=0; $col<4; $col++){

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow ($col, $rowCount, $row1 ['id']);
        }

        $rowCount++;
    }
```

Related : [PHPExcel setCellValueByColumnAndRow not writing data to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468606/phpexcel-setcellvaluebycolumnandrow-not-writing-data-to-spreadsheet)

Comment: Using your idea I'm getting all the results repeated in each column.